# SQL Union with coalesce(?) in where clause

Tags: sql, web-applications, db2, union

I am trying to incorporate old help desk records into a newer help desk app. I still have all the data from the old help desk app and it uses the same fields as the new one but its in a different file. This select statement works fine for the newer application to search all the past calls for something specific, whether its a keyword or who it is allocated to and so on.

```
SELECT status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
 FROM   helpdesk.table1
 WHERE  UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) 
  AND   identity = coalesce(?, identity) 
  AND   description = coalesce(?, description) 
  AND   contact= coalesce(?, contact) 
  AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext)
  and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)
 ORDER by allocated, identity desc
```

What I am trying to do is use some kind of union so I can just have one box to search both the newer and the old records, instead of two different boxes and having to remember where the data might be stored. I was thinking something like this might work but I think my where clause is too ambiguous and I tried just about every combination of including a library in front of the fields.

```
Select *
From
(
select status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
 from helpdesk.table1
Union                                   
select status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
 from helpdesk.table2
)
WHERE   UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) 
  AND   identity = coalesce(?, identity) 
  AND   description = coalesce(?, description) 
  AND   contact= coalesce(?, contact) 
  AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext)
  and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)
 ORDER by allocated, identity desc
```

If I do just the union with the two selects, I get all the records from both tables but i need to be able to narrow the results to a keyword or some other kind of field like in the first block of code. If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Also I probably should have said that it is db2 and the sql is running on a web app. So when this sql runs it generates either drop down boxes or a text field to put your own words into to narrow down the results of all the help desk calls.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry about that, pretty sure it is db2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is specific to the web app generator that I am using or if you can use it other places in different SQL, but you can reference the parameters and pass them behind the scenes with something called a **parameter parameter** which are the ??1, ??2, ??3 in the second half of the union. This solved the problem of having two sets of boxes for user input by just passing what you enter in the first where. Here is the final version of code that works for me

```
SELECT status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
FROM   helpdesk.table1
WHERE  UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) 
 AND   identity = coalesce(?, identity) 
 AND   description = coalesce(?, description) 
 AND   contact= coalesce(?, contact) 
 AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext)
 and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)

Union

SELECT status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
FROM   helpdesk.table2
WHERE  UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(??1, allocated_to) 
 AND   identity = coalesce(??2, identity) 
 AND   description = coalesce(??3, description) 
 AND   contact= coalesce(??4, contact) 
 AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(??5,scantext)
 and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(??6, extended_desc)
ORDER by allocated, identity desc
```

Thank you for those that tried to help me out though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just put the where in both select statements that you're trying to union.  Might be faster than combining both tables, then filtering.

```
SELECT * FROM  helpdesk.table1
WHERE   UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) 
  AND   identity = coalesce(?, identity) 
  AND   description = coalesce(?, description) 
  AND   contact= coalesce(?, contact) 
  AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext)
  and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM  helpdesk.table2
WHERE   UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) 
  AND   identity = coalesce(?, identity) 
  AND   description = coalesce(?, description) 
  AND   contact= coalesce(?, contact) 
  AND UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext)
  and upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)
ORDER BY allocated, identity desc;
```

just put the order by after the second select.  `UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, UPPER(allocated_to))` syntax might work better also if you're worried about case.

Comment: The problem with that is this is running through a web app and when you do the where for both of them it then shows two sets of boxes to fill out on the web app. That is what I am trying to get around.

Comment: ah.. I figured you were using some kind a paramaterized solution.. not familiar with self generating web apps

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an indicator of which table a record comes from.  If so:

```
Select *
From (select 'old' as which, status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
      from helpdesk.table1
      Union all                                
      select 'new', status, identity, description, contact, scan_text, extended_desc, allocated_to
      from helpdesk.table2
     ) hd
WHERE UPPER(allocated_to) = coalesce(?, allocated_to) AND
      identity = coalesce(?, identity) AND
      description = coalesce(?, description) AND
      contact= coalesce(?, contact) AND
     UPPER(scan_text) LIKE coalesce(?,scantext) AND
     upper(extended_desc) like coalesce(?, extended_desc)
ORDER by allocated, identity desc;
```

You can then add the appropriate `where` logic on the `which` column (and rename the column to whatever you would like as well).

Comment: No, what I am trying to do is just have one prompt that relates to both the newer records and the older records. It does not really matter where the data comes from, as long it is referencing both tables